# open Google maps from webview link on Android Studio 2

Tags: android

I am developing an small app where I have dynamic data and once is clicked, then must open the native google maps.
Instead of this, I get this errormessage:
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

this is the code that I have

```
mapLink='geo:0,0?q='+localidad+" "+direccionTemp;
window.location.href = mapLink;
```

Should I make some changes in android Studio 2?
I am really noob.
Please help

Comment: i believe that error message means that your URL layout isnt the right layout as google wants it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to parse your URL Put below code in your onClickListener:

```
Double myLatitude = //Your Latitude;
   Double myLongitude = //Your Longitude;
   String labelLocation = Your Label";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">?q=<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">(" + labelLocation + ")"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can omit (LabelLocation) if you don't want a label.

Comment: thanks, Where do I have to write that?
just modify the link? .
Well, just modified and still not working :(

Comment: Another question..
Where must be that click listener? at webview java file?I am lost :(

Comment: It depends.. If you are displaying the link inside TextView you can set onClickListener on that TextView and put this code inside When the user clicks on the TextView he will be presented with a map with set coordinates or you can also put this code inside Button onClickListener.

Comment: Thanks for answer
I just want to open in native google maps.
I wrote the code that I have. Can you help me to understand why is not working?

Comment: Sorry for this new command, but I really wat to do is that when I click a dynamic button un webview, the sistem open the native google maps with the dynamic address
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have
Javascript:
`mapLink='geo:0,0?q='+localidad+" "+direccionTemp;
window.location.href = mapLink;`

Android Studio 2:
MainActivity:

`public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                url = url.replaceFirst("mailto:", "");
                url = url.trim();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("plain/text").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{url});
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }else {
                if (url.startsWith("geo:")) {
                    Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(searchAddress);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }`

Manifest.xml:
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
...
Whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: Hi
Still not working
This is drining me crazy
Any sample to download to understand how to open the google maps from dynamic link in webview?

Answer (score 0):

Please paste after code in section: `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

```
 //Error open link Google map webview:
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith(("https://maps.google.com/?q=")) )) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity (
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

For example, you want to insert a place on Google, just enter the address name after the link: **https://maps.google.com/?q=....Place-name**
So the app will recognize that this is a google map link and redirect to the Google map app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).